# Jenkins Official Mobile App for Android

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there any official Jenkins mobile app for android where I can create/configure/run/monitor the builds using the app?

I could find JenkinsMobi V4 - mobile API and Plugin for Jenkins on Mobile. here is the link https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsMobi+V4+-+mobile+API+and+Plugin+for+Jenkins+on+Mobile but I understand this is a plugin.

There is an android app in google play by MobiLab solutions, but I understand this is an unofficial Jenkins client for Android platform.

I am not able to find any official Jenkins app in the Android Play Store.

If I have to use Jenkins from my mobile (android) then do I need to manually launch the Jenkins URL from the browser in my mobile (http://MachineIP:8080) and start using it or is there any official app which I can download and connect it to the IP and then start using it.

Kindly Help!

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "official" app of jenkins. But I believe it is a good idea to have one.

Comment: okay.. Thanks for the info...

Answer (score 2):

There is no official app. The [Jenkins Mobi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilabsolutions.jenkins.app) app for Android is probably the most well-maintained of the unofficial apps though.

Comment: This app seems to have been removed from the play store some time recently -- Google has cached pages from May 1 2018 with it present, but as of May 24 it's missing.